# Mocking $resourceProvider in AngularJs & Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my controller I am using  $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService the could help me to fetch data from the server.

```
    controllers.controller("testController", [
        "$scope", "$resource", "$rootScope", "$http",
        "$window", "$location", "resourceService",
        function ($scope, $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService, $rootScope: IRootScope, 
                  $http, $window, $location, resourceService: services.IResourceService) {    ...//implementation
    }]);
```

And here is my attempt of Jasmine unit test. However, I am getting 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
How would you mock $resourceProvider?

```
    describe("testController Tests", function (): void {
        var vm: createDailylog.IViewModel;
        var $scope: ng.IScope;
        var $rootScope;
        var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
        //var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngResource']);
        var $resource = $injector.get('$resource');

        beforeEach(function (): void {
            module("controllers");
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_: ng.IControllerService,
            _$httpBackend_, _$resource_, _$rootScope_: IRootScope, $injector) {

            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            //$resource = _$resource_;

            this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend; 

            $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();

            $rootScope.config = {
                serverUrl: "https://test.domainName.net/",
                serverVersion: "test", 
                title: "Test Server Reference"
            };


            //instantiating controller
            vm = _$controller_('testController', {
                $scope: $scope,
                $resource: $injector.get("$resource"),
                $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
                $window: {},
                $location: {}
            });
        }));

        //afterEach(function () {
        //    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        //    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        //}); 

        describe('when populate method is called', function () {

            it("should create controller!", function () {

                $httpBackend.flush();
                expect(true).toBe(true);
            });
        });

       );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to mock `$resource`?  You should only be mocking data, which is coming from `$http`; you seem to be doing that already.